# Plotting curved line in Python Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to plot curved/arced lines on a Basemap map.
I can plot a straight line using map.plot(x,y,..), but how do I make it curved/have arrows?

In matplotlib, this can be done using annotate(..), but Basemap doesn't have this method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, found one solution, i.e. simply to draw on matplotlib.pyplot instead of the map object. However, this does not allow me to do things like "wrapping around" the globe with a line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very old question, but I thought it might be good to answer anyway. When you said curved lines, I assumed you meant drawing a [great circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle). There is an example of doing exactly that in the [basemap documentation](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/users/examples.html), which I have modified to make a little more easy to modify yourself:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='cyl')

p0_ll =  -73.98, 40.78
p1_ll = 0.08, 51.53

m.drawgreatcircle(p0_ll[0], p0_ll[1], p1_ll[0], p1_ll[1], 
                  linewidth=2, color='b')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the great circle method cannot handle the crossing of the edges of the map ([as mentioned in the documentation](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawgreatcircle)), which, although clearly documented, is a pretty major flaw IMHO.

Hope that helps somebody,