# Plotting sphere grid with matplotlib basemap

Tags: matplotlib, map-projections, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to draw a grid covering all the sphere on an orthographic projection.
The issue is cells outside the projection are not drawed correctly. This happened with `drawgreatcircles` as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451451/plotting-curved-line-in-python-basemap).

I have also tried to use Polygons as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251189/how-to-draw-rectangles-on-a-basemap), but same problem.

Finally, I have coded a custom check based on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection_(cartography)#Mathematics). The idea is for each point of each segment, we check `cos c` (cf Wikipedia) and do not plot it if the cosinus is negative.

My question is : can we do this kind of check with basemap own functions ?
This strategy would not work for other projections.

Also, why is this kind of check not included in Basemap ?

Comment: What kind of grid? Is it just a simple regular global grid? I'm sure we can do some workaround to get Basemap to plot this, you might consider looking at cartopy (as yet, unannounced) which might "just work".

Comment: Unfortunately, the grid is irregular but all cells are rectangular (in lat-lon coordinates). I can easily compute the center and width/height of each cell, though. 
I will check cartopy, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your example, I took the data and plotted it with cartopy. The following changes were needed to create the plot:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
ax =plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic())
plt.pcolormesh(lons, lats,val, edgecolors='k', 
               linewidths=1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()

plt.show()
```

[image: output using cartopy]

This is using pcolormesh so is pretty quick (though your example wasn't that slow on my machine in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using pcolor :

```
import pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

nb_lat2 = 20
nb_lat = 2*nb_lat2
nb_lon = 3*(2*(nb_lat+1) - 1)
lats = np.zeros((2*nb_lat, nb_lon))
lons = np.zeros((2*nb_lat, nb_lon))
val = np.zeros((2*nb_lat, nb_lon))
dlat = 90./nb_lat2
for i in range(nb_lat):

  nb_lon = 2*(i+1)-1
  if ((i+1) > nb_lat2):
    nb_lon = 2*(nb_lat - i)-1

  dlon = 120./nb_lon
  lats[2*i][:] = 90 - i*dlat
  lats[2*i+1][:] = 90 - (i+1)*dlat
  for j in range(nb_lon):
    lons[2*i][j] = j*dlon
    lons[2*i+1][j] = j*dlon

    for k in range(1,3):
      lons[2*i][j + k*nb_lon] = j*dlon + 120.*k
      lons[2*i+1][j + k*nb_lon] = j*dlon + 120.*k

    lons[2*i][3*nb_lon:] = nb_lon*dlon + 240.
    lons[2*i+1][3*nb_lon:] = nb_lon*dlon + 240.

lons = lons - 180
val = lats + lons
# Crash
##m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution=None)

#m = Basemap(projection='mill',lon_0=0)
m = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=0,lon_0=0)
x, y = m(lons, lats)
m.pcolor(x,y,val, edgecolors='k', linewidths=1)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,91.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,60.))

plt.show()
```

This does exactly what I want : drawing rectangles and filling them with one color.
But it is very slow (too slow). A lot of cells are unused : at the end of a latidude line, we set the width of unused cells to 0.

Another issue is some projections crash (Robin for example).